# Vega Lite Independent Scale with Multiple Layers and Facet

Tags: vega, vega-lite

Is it possible to have an independent scale for each facet and each layer? The resolve works great when you have either a facet or an extra layer, but I cannot get it to do both, wondering if it is even possible.

What I want is:
[The two scales on each side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqOYx.png)

mixed with
[the faceting here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZRY4.png)

Comment: This should be possible by putting the layer within a facet, but that does not work currently due to a bug in Vega-Lite. See https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/4373

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way this would be expressed in Vega-Lite is using a layer, with resolve set, within a facet. Something like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/seattle-weather.csv"
  },
  "facet": {
    "column": {
      "field": "weather",
      "type": "nominal"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "layer": [
      {
        "encoding": {
          "x": {
            "field": "date",
            "timeUnit": "month",
            "type": "temporal"
          },
          "y": {
            "aggregate": "mean",
            "field": "temp_max",
            "type": "quantitative"
          }
        },
        "mark": {
          "color": "salmon",
          "type": "line"
        }
      },
      {
        "encoding": {
          "x": {
            "field": "date",
            "timeUnit": "month",
            "type": "temporal"
          },
          "y": {
            "aggregate": "mean",
            "field": "precipitation",
            "type": "quantitative"
          }
        },
        "mark": {
          "color": "steelblue",
          "type": "line"
        }
      }
    ],
    "resolve": {
      "scale": {
        "y": "independent"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

While this spec is valid according to the Vega-Lite schema, there is unfortunately a [bug](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/4373) in the vega-lite renderer that makes it unable to render this spec.

As a workaround, you can manually concatenate two layered charts with a filter transform that selects the desired subset of data for each. For example:

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/seattle-weather.csv"
  },
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {"type": "line", "color": "salmon"},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"type": "temporal", "field": "date", "timeUnit": "month"},
            "y": {
              "type": "quantitative",
              "aggregate": "mean",
              "field": "temp_max"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {"type": "line", "color": "steelblue"},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"type": "temporal", "field": "date", "timeUnit": "month"},
            "y": {
              "type": "quantitative",
              "aggregate": "mean",
              "field": "precipitation"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "independent", "x": "shared"}},
      "transform": [{"filter": "(datum.weather === 'sun')"}]
    },
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {"type": "line", "color": "salmon"},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"type": "temporal", "field": "date", "timeUnit": "month"},
            "y": {
              "type": "quantitative",
              "aggregate": "mean",
              "field": "temp_max"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {"type": "line", "color": "steelblue"},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"type": "temporal", "field": "date", "timeUnit": "month"},
            "y": {
              "type": "quantitative",
              "aggregate": "mean",
              "field": "precipitation"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "independent", "x": "shared"}},
      "transform": [{"filter": "(datum.weather === 'fog')"}]
    }
  ],
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.6.0.json"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - I think I'll keep an eye on the bug. This is a good workaround, my script takes dynamic inputs though so not sure I want to re-write the script to check field length and hconcat/vconcat everything