# Deneb plot (Vega-Lite) for Power BI: How to use an free scale y-axis with facet

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite, deneb

I am using Deneb custom visual to repeat visual for different tasks. Is it possible to only show the relevent Y-axis values. Following data is used:

[image]

The following Vega-lite JSON is used:

```
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "mark": {
    "type": "bar",
    "opacity": 1,
    "tooltip": true,
    "cornerRadius": 15
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Earliest StartDate",
      "type": "temporal"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "MachGrpCode",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": {
        "title": null,
        "grid": true,
        "tickBand": "extent"
      }
    },
    "row": {
      "field": "ProdHeaderOrdNr",
      "header": {"labelAngle": 0}
    }
  },
  "resolve": {
    "axis": {
      "x": "independent",
      "y": "independent"
    }
  }
}
```

Which results in:
[image]

Is it possible to only use the relevent task values (for 022 --> erase 6700 row)?

Comment: Please provide a full dataset in copiable text format. Please also mark your previous question as solved if it was correctly answered.

Answer (score 0):

From [what I've seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787262/vega-lite-independent-scale-with-multiple-layers-and-facet), this is a [Vega bug](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/4373). The recommended work-around is to use `vconcat` with a `filter` `transform`. If you only have a few `ProdHeaderOrdNr`, this is doable.

[image: Fixed]

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoAAoAnNsoAScJMrhmA8meUA5M2hAAmAAxeviiAAskiwAOJmOADClnCeAGw+SYEAokhmwvqYAAQAyupmmAAianHovl4AzPx+NQEAvgqmFta29k4u7p4VAUoh4ZEx9gkAjMlKaRk0WXkFxaXdftW1PvEgjc2WNnYOzm4e5X69waEwEdGxCQAc4yCTmRA5+enzmGXeS3U1AOzrTSDmLZtXadA4gSojb5iQL9M6DS7oRK3e7TR6zF4lN6Lfz8EZeXGVP6bVo7Dr7TwQqEw07nIbveJjHypdIPJ5zTHvHq4-EjAAsRIBLW27T2XXQlOhfRp8OGiO+yJZqLZGIWhyqNRGuOh9QAuo0QMQoHIoGojKBMGYkLIIAAzNhmBBmkA2miCN5g1SYBgISiAkki0HZAC8QeyAHIemH1jqlMgzABrNDmgCeOHeTHSgTYOFCdGTaBGSkwbDYbpoODQFr0SiNZlkDgASnYaAwDKgRmJ9XBZEblDRZGQkyAAB5Dl1wQTKTwombPQocwKYVPvN4IHD2nR-ED5zTO6aTzyw2mXIvLzyyNgIfubpRIYc0NvmuiCMqyBiCQRKMhmGhT1BVuAixoKB4wAIStP8QDgYc3lkTB1nqRD-gtK1bXtR1UGMPc3QcTxPW9X0hWBMl3GDUMwwlKNdVjdJE13Jc008DMPCUbNcyXAsixLMsK3-MxqxAWt6zMJs+1bAtOyUbte37Qdd1HXdxwPdAZzROdXjiU9GPQVd10tQQtx3UAlMgo8ZU0kAGPeC8r1kG8QDvB8h0wZ9X3fT8QG-X9K34wDLOAsCIM8aDYPgxDEL1IA)